# Give limited access to android app using Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have created an android app using phonegap. I want to run the app to limit its usage to only 5 times means user can open this app only for 5 times after that user will not be able to open it instead it will show a message.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements you could probably have a setting that you increment and save every time the app is opened, then when you see the app is over it's open limit you'd block access.

With this method clearing the data on the phone would reset the value.  For this to be very reliable you'd have to have some sort of device ID that gets sent to a server that would determine if the app has been opened before and how many times.